# signal that a batch of threads has finished to a masterthread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

I think I miss a fundamental design pattern concerning multiprogramming.
I got at solution to a problem but I would say its overly complex.

At program start, I'm allocating a static pool of workers and a master thread, that live throughout the program run. (pseudocode below)

```
void *worker(){
   while(1){
   //perworker mutex lock
   //wait for workerSIGNAL
   //do calculations
   //perworker mutex unlock
   }
}
```

My master thread signals all my workers, when the workers are done, they wait for the next signal from the master thread. (pseudocode below)

```
void *master(){
  while(1){
    //masterMutex lock
    //wait for masterSignal
    //signal all workerthread to start running
    /*
      SHOULD WAIT FOR ALL WORKER THREADS TO FINISH 
      (that is when workers are done with the calculations,
      and are waiting for a new signal) 
     */
    //materMutex unlock
  }
}
```

My master thread gets a signal from another part of my code (non thread), which means that only one masterthread exists. (pseudocode below)

```
double callMaster(){
  //SIGNAL masterThread
  //return value that is the result of the master thread
}
```

My problem is, how do I make the masterthread wait for all the workers to be done (waiting for next workerSignal) ?

My solution is extraordinary complex.
I have a barrier in my workerthreads, that waits for all worker threads to finish, then from one of my threads (threadId=0),I signal a workerDone conditional that is being waited for in the bottom of my masterthread.

It works but its not beautiful, any ideas for improvements is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using `pthread_join` http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html? It sounds like your using a signal to communicate between threads. While this might be appropriate in some situations I think in your case you might find the use of pthread_join simplifies your code.

I've outlined some example pseudo-code below:

```
//this goes in your main thread
for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
    pthread_join(thread_id[i], ...
```

This way your main thread will block until all threads, your worker threads, in the `thread_id` array have terminated.

Comment: This is *the* way to do it for POSIX threads. If instead some other synchronization is used, the only guarantees that the worker will have truly terminated (i.e. the final `}` is reached) when the master is awoken are those of the system scheduler/system thread model, things which you don't want to rely on at this level.

Comment: `pthread_join` is wrong. OP wants the worker threads to wait for the next round then continue, not exit.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a barrier. Barriers are initialized with a count `N`, and when any thread calls `pthread_barrier_wait`, it blocks until a total of `N` threads are at `pthread_barrier_wait`, and then they all return and the barrier can be used again (with the same count).

See the documentation in POSIX for details:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can use a Cyclic Barrier here with an initial value equal to the number of worker threads.

A reference to this barrier is passed to each worker thread, who, at the end of a single execution of their work, call barrier.await().

The main program will await() at the barrier until all worker threads have reached the point in their execution and called barrier.await().

Only when all worker threads have called barrier.await() will the barrier be raised and main may continue.

Cyclic barriers are similar to Latches, except that the barrier is cyclical, allowing it to be reset indefinately. 
So in the case of main being in a loop, a cyclic barrier is a better option.